# Getting iPhone geodata

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation, augmented-reality

I am developing an augmented reality app and I need to use the iPhone sensors to obtain the following information/data:

- geographic latitude, longitude and altitude (to provide location relative to earth’s surface and mean sea level)
- phone viewpoint central heading (0°=N, 90°=E, 180°=S, 270°=W)
- phone viewpoint central elevation (0°=horizontal, -90°=vertical downwards, +90°=vertical upwards)
- phone tilt (0°=portrait/upright, 90°=landscape/top points left, 180°=landscape/top points down, 270°=portrait/top points down)
- phone angle subtended vertically (ie. along nominal top to bottom)
- phone angle subtended horizontally (ie. along nominal side to side)

I already know hot to find latitude, longitude and altitude, I was wondering what kind of API or library I could use to find the other data, like the phone angle and the phone viewpoint etc. What API would I use? Some sample code? Links? Discussion? Im just trying to figure out how to find this data!

Comment: Actually, I believe that it is about geotagging - http://ajnaware.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/geotagging-and-augmented-reality-new-standards-needed/

Comment: @Daij-Djan It is iOS specific as I need to use the iphone sensors to get the data, and it is geotagging, maybe Im remixing the use of the term slightly, but geotags can contain altitude, bearings yada yada

Comment: surely you can use a compass for point 2 and an accelerometer for point 4

---

points 3 5 6 could MAYBE be calculated from the Location's altitude + the angle you need for 4?!

Comment: I believe the question was asking HOW.

Answer (score 2):

The information you mentioned can be gotten through CoreLocation and CoreMotion APIs (As mentioned by Jeremy on the [iOS Dev Scout Facebook Group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/iosdevscout/).

You can get

- Location Sensors (aGPS, Cell Tower, WiFi) - Latitude, Longitude, Altitude, Speed, Course, etc.
- Gyroscope & Accelerometer - Rotation and Translation of the device.
- Magnetometer - North and True North.

An sample AR project are available in iOS Developer Library named [pARk](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/pARk/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011083).

The accompanied WWDC session that spawn this sample project is the 2011 one, named 423: Understanding Core Motion.

Check out the WWDC 2012 sessions related to Core Motion too to strengthen your knowledge in these area.

Hopefully this helps. With these information its not hard to derives the value you need from CoreLocation (for your first point) and CoreMotion (for your next 5 points).

Answer (score 0):

Add the **Core Motion** framework to your project.

Create an instance of **CMMotionManager**:

```
_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.00/60.00;
[_motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
```

Get the CMDeviceMotion reference:

```
CMDeviceMotion *currentDeviceMotion = _motionManager.deviceMotion;
```

To get the **Attitude** (combination of Pitch, Roll and Yaw):

```
CMAttitude *currentAttitude = currentDeviceMotion.attitude;
```

To get the **pitch** (rotation around a lateral axis that passes through the iPhone):

```
currentAttitude.pitch
```

To get the **roll** (rotation around a longitudinal axis from top to bottom):

```
currentAttitude.roll
```

To get the **yaw** (rotation around an axis that runs vertically through the iPhone):

```
currentAttitude.yaw
```

This should help to get the other device data like angle and tilt, and when combined with the **Core Location** framework you should be able to get everything you need.